# jQuery Validation error class affects Select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-validate

When a validation error occurs on a `<select>` form element after pressing the submit button, the `errorClass` appears to be applied to the `<select>` element which is not what I want. `errorClass` should only be applied to the error message.

**Question:** How can we avoid that problem?

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ufTn8/

[image]

---

### Update

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/SPK3D

If you take a look at updated code, when the error occurs, the class `alert` is not applied to the error element until u click on the error element... this strange behavior is seen in both Chrome and Firefox.

Somehow `$(element).siblings('label.error').addClass('alert');` did not add the `alert` class initially...

Comment: What do you want? Also, the fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: Please include the code in the OP so that this question is not reliant upon the health of an external link.  Thanks.

Comment: @tymeJV errorClass should be applied only to the error messages

Comment: That's not how this plugin was designed.  The specified or default error class is applied to the element with the error.

Comment: @Sparky oh the correct method to use should be the `highlight` method?

Comment: Actually, the correct method would be to use both `highlight` and `unhighlight`.  Then you can over-ride this default behavior to do whatever you need.

Comment: Updated OP with a strange new problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions to apply whatever class you wish to whatever element you wish.  Below are the default functions.  By including them as options inside `.validate()`, you can over-ride these defaults with whatever code you wish.

```
    highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
        if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
        if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
            this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:

Regarding OP's amended question,

> *"Somehow `$(element).siblings('label.error').addClass('alert');` did not add the alert class initially..."*

That's because you are trying to select `label.error` and it does not exist yet. You must have a `label.error` *before* you can select it and apply `.alert`... those two things can't happen simultaneously.

A workaround might include changing the default `errorClass` for the plugin to `.alert` and then using `highlight` and `unhighlight` to apply whatever *other* classes need to be applied to the `select` element.

See:  http://jsfiddle.net/SPK3D/1/

Comment: Thanks! If you take a look at updated code at http://jsfiddle.net/SPK3D/, when the error occurs, the class `alert` is not applied to the error element **until** u click on the error element... any ideas?

Comment: Great answer. I was able to use this to stop radio and select fields from throwing errors.